Screen does not go blank in 24.10
For some reason, my screen does not go blank after upgrading to 24.10. I have the screen blank setting set to 10 minutes, and the system does not seem to follow that. I even set it to shorter time period, e.g. 1 minute, but it never worked.
I eventually stumbled upon discussions suggesting I can issue xset s 600 600 to set the screen saver time. However, it doesn't work, and after some time it got reset to 0 when I checked xset q
$ xset q

Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On

I am running Ubuntu 24.10 under X, and with nvidia display driver 560.

I've got the same issue since 24.10. Did you resolve the issue? In my case, I'm using Wayland with NVIDIA. Nothing obvious is showing up in dmesg when the screen should be timing out.

oh so i should check dmesg for this? nope the screen still doesn't go blank

No need to check it, no. I just added the info to indicate that this is at least one of the sources that might have given a clue but it's of no use. Other systems logs don't give me anything to go on either.
